# cmdlets not recognized on the first run in powershell

Tags: function, powershell

I am facing an issue with the first run of powershell code.

1. cmdlets and user defined function are not recognized in the first run but works fine if I run the code again
2. user defined function takes values from previous run.i.e. basically we need to run the code twice to get the correct result

Code:

```
$resultVar=get-CPUAndMemUtilization -computername $computername -CPUCriteria $CPUCriteria -MemCriteria $MemCriteria
#Write-Host  "Mme:"$resultVar;
$CPUMem += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        CPULoad = "$($resultVar[0])" 
        MemLoad = "$($resultVar[1])" 
} 
Write-Host $CPUMem;


function get-CPUAndMemUtilization($computername,$CPUCriteria,$MemCriteria)
{

    $Memstatus=$null;
    $CPUstatus=$null;
    $AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor |  Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
    $OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = {“{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) }} 
    $result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        ServerName = "$computername" 
        CPULoad = "$($AVGProc.Average)%" 
        MemLoad = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%" 
    } 

    if($AVGProc.Average -lt $CPUCriteria)
    {
        $Memstatus=1;
    }else{
        $Memstatus=0;
    }


    if($OS.MemoryUsage -lt $MemCriteria)
    {
        $CPUstatus=1;
    }else{
        $CPUstatus=0;
    } 

    $CPUstatus
    $Memstatus
return;
}
```

Code return the System CPU & Me usage of the system in CPU & Mem utilization for a system
Error:

> get-CPUAndMemUtilization : The term 'get-CPUAndMemUtilization' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
>   verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Sorry, Added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the function before you import it (so it doesn't exist) into the powershell session, just swap those 2 things:

```
function get-CPUAndMemUtilization($computername,$CPUCriteria,$MemCriteria)
{
...
}
$resultVar=get-CPUAndMemUtilization -computername $computername -CPUCriteria $CPUCriteria -MemCriteria $MemCriteria
#Write-Host  "Mme:"$resultVar;
$CPUMem += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        CPULoad = "$($resultVar[0])" 
        MemLoad = "$($resultVar[1])" 
} 
Write-Host $CPUMem;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick turnaround .Seems to be working